# Error in Python: name 'df' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Im new in python, many hours googled and search here in stackoverflow. But still have problem with my code. I need run *foo* function in time interval, and fill dataframe (eg every second add timestamp to df). I'm still coming across a error message:  **NameError:** *name 'df' is not defined*

Thank you for your answer.

Code:

```
    WAIT_TIME_SECONDS = 1


class ProgramKilled(Exception):
    pass

    df = pd.DataFrame([])

############################################################
############################################################
def foo():

    global df
    time1 = str(datetime.now())
    time2 = time1.replace(":", "_")
    print(time2)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= {
    'timestamp': [time2],
    'cas_zapas_1_text': ['cas']
    })

    df = df.append(df2)

############################################################
############################################################
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise ProgramKilled

class Job(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, execute, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = False
        self.stopped = threading.Event()
        self.interval = interval
        self.execute = execute
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def stop(self):
                self.stopped.set()
                self.join()
    def run(self):
            while not self.stopped.wait(self.interval.total_seconds()):
                self.execute(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    job = Job(interval=timedelta(seconds=WAIT_TIME_SECONDS), execute=foo)
    job.start()

    while True:
          try:
              time.sleep(1)
          except ProgramKilled:
              print("Program killed: running cleanup code")
              job.stop()
              break
```

This is resultof script:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Miro/.spyder-py3/untitled8.py', wdir='C:/Users/Miro/.spyder-py3')
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miro\Anaconda3\envs\spyder_4_0_1\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Miro\.spyder-py3\untitled8.py", line 90, in run
    self.execute(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miro\.spyder-py3\untitled8.py", line 68, in foo
    df = df.append(df2)
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
2020-06-16 08_29_31.920157
Program killed: running cleanup code
```

Comment: you didn't define the dataframe `df`. maybe this line should be indented outside `df = pd.DataFrame([])`

Comment: Please post the traceback so we can easily spot where the error occurs. And consider trimming down the example. Less code to paw through equals happy reviewers.

Comment: @tdelaney  question is updated

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame([])` is indented so its part of the class definition. Its not a module level variable. But there is also a `pass` at the top of the class definition, suggesting that you really wanted the variable to be a module level. In that case, dedent that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `global df` before `class ProgramKilled(Exception):`

Comment: Many thanks, I add  "global df" and "df = pd.DataFrame([])" before "class ProgramKilled(Exception):" and script goes as I need.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to add `global df` above the class definition. It is only used inside function definitions. And the `df` could be below the class as well as above. The problem was the wrong indentation.

Answer (score 0):

It means df is a class variable and not work.

```py
class ProgramKilled(Exception):
    pass

    df = pd.DataFrame([])
```

If not a class variable, you should change it as following

```py
class ProgramKilled(Exception):
    pass
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
...
df = pd.DataFrame([])
...
```

If you need to define it there, I think it's not a good choice.

```
class ProgramKilled(Exception):
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame([])
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You made `df` part of the `ProgramKilled` class namespace. Just dedent it and it becomes a module level variable. Functions that want to assign it later use `global df` - but you're already doing that part correctly in your code.

Just change to

```
class ProgramKilled(Exception):
    pass

df = pd.DataFrame([])
```

Comment: I made a change as you wrote and the script works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpful and quick answers. This solution works:

```
    WAIT_TIME_SECONDS = 1

global df
df = pd.DataFrame([])

class ProgramKilled(Exception):
    pass



############################################################
############################################################
def foo():

    global df
    time1 = str(datetime.now())
    time2 = time1.replace(":", "_")
    print(time2)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= {
    'timestamp': [time2],
    'cas_zapas_1_text': ['cas']
    })

    df = df.append(df2)

############################################################
############################################################
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise ProgramKilled

class Job(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, execute, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = False
        self.stopped = threading.Event()
        self.interval = interval
        self.execute = execute
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def stop(self):
                self.stopped.set()
                self.join()
    def run(self):
            while not self.stopped.wait(self.interval.total_seconds()):
                self.execute(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    job = Job(interval=timedelta(seconds=WAIT_TIME_SECONDS), execute=foo)
    job.start()

    while True:
          try:
              time.sleep(1)
          except ProgramKilled:
              print("Program killed: running cleanup code")
              job.stop()
              break
```

Comment: No need for that `global df`. The problem was simply the indentation.